# Изменение класса у нескольких дивов по id

Tags: javascript

Есть код, в котором содержимое страницы меняется по прошествию определенного времени - у нужного id меняется класс.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="Stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script><!--JQ-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script><!--JQEQ-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="effects.core.full.js"></script><!--JQEQ-->
<script>
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1041';}, 0500);
</script>
</head>
<style>
    .my_1040 {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;}
    .my_1041 {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue;}
</style>
<body>

<table class="my_1040" id="hr40">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос:
Как изменить класс у нескольких div'ов с одинаковыми id ? (данный скрипт меняет только у первого)

Comment: Вы говорите ерунду. По спецификации атрибут `id` должен быть уникальным у каждого элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с ошибки: `id` элемента должен быть уникальным. Т.е. не может быть нескольких элементов с одинаковым `айди`.

Т.е. я бы сделал так: у нескольких элементов общий класс-идентификатор, по которому будет выполняться поиск и изменение класса:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
        <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="Stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script><!--JQ-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script><!--JQEQ-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="effects.core.full.js"></script><!--JQEQ-->
        <script>
            /**
             * jquery style
             */
            $(function() {
                $('.class-ident').addClass('my_1041');
            });

            /**
             * native
             */
            window.onload = function() {
                /**
                 * получаем список элементов с классом "class-ident"
                 */
                var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('class-ident');

                /**
                 * в цикле добавляем каждому элементу класс "my_1041"
                 */
                for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    elems[i].className += ' my_1041';
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <style>
        .my_1040 {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;}
        .my_1041 {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue;}
    </style>
    <body>

        <div class='class-ident'></div>
        <div class='class-ident'></div>
        <div class='class-ident'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @lampa - Спасибо. Но.. Сам это написал. Решил вот узнать, можно ли все же перебрать несколько элементов с одинаковым ID. 

    <div id='hr40'></div>
    <div id='hr40'></div>
    <div id='hr40'></div>
    <div id='hr40'></div>

если на мой вопрос есть четкий ответ 'нет' - для меня это тоже информация

Comment: @mixalef можно и голову разбить об стену, но адекватный человек этого не станет делать. Также и тут, можно проставить одинаковые id элементам, но в адекватной работоспособности скрипта не ждите. Т.е. нет, нельзя делать так, чтобы на страницы были элементы с одинаковым id.

Comment: Чётко: [НЕТ][1].

>The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Неуникальные id противоречат спецификации, следовательно, инструментов для работы с ними не существует.

  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: ну.. это тоже ответ. просто думал, чего то не знаю. Жаль конечно