# Изменение id у элемента, с дальнейшей работой

Tags: javascript

Вчера, наткнулся на [камень преткновения в JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/234751/javascript-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-id) , и писить против ветра оказалось невозможно.

Собственно есть страница (не моя), в моем случае с двумя одинаковыми `id`.. печаль.. Но все же с первым `id` - javascript работает. Можно ли каким то образом с помощью js/jq изменить первому нужному элементу сам `id`? и потом уже с помощью JS обратиться и к нему, по новому `id`, и к тому, второму элементу, с таким же `id` ?

Знаю, многим вопрос не понравиться, охота 2м элементам сделать новый класс

```
function(){document.getElementById('my_class').className += 'hide_my';}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<b id="x">123</b>
<b id="x">321</b>    
<script>
    alert(document.getElementById('x').innerHTML);
    document.getElementById('x').id = 'x2';
    alert(document.getElementById('x2').innerHTML);
    alert(document.getElementById('x').innerHTML);
</script>
```

1. выводит 123
2. выводит 123
3. выводит 321

---

**Вариант2** который вам тоже может пригодиться:

```
<b id="x">123</b>
<b id="x">321</b>

<script>
    list1 = document.getElementsByTagName('b');
    for (var i=0; i<list1.length; i++)
    {
        if (list1[i].id == "x")
        {
            alert(list1[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
</script>
```

тут уже можно получить ко всем элементам с одинаковыми id :)

Comment: <div id='element'></div>
  <div id='element'></div>

  <script>
  var elem1 = document.getElementById('element');
  elem1.setAttribute('id', elem1.getAttribute('id') + Math.random());

  var elem2 = document.getElementById('element');

  elem1.innerHTML = '1';
  elem2.innerHTML = '2';
  </script>

Comment: ой, что-то невнимательно прочитал )